# A somewhat pathological function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request

For educational purposes, I need a function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that meets the following properties, or a proof that it doesn't exist:

- Continuous.
- For every $x\in\Bbb R$, $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is infinite and bounded.

I have been thinking on the problem for a while, and intuition tells me that such a function doesn't exist, but I'm not sure where to begin to find a proof.

Hints for a proof or a counterexample (or a reference for it) are welcome.

Comment: You mean $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is **infinite** (not "infinity").

Comment: whatsome --> somewhat?

Comment: whatsome --> mewhat? dang you were faster @HennoBrandsma

Comment: Maybe a variation of $sin(1/x)/x$, which seems to work except at $0$?

Comment: $f(x)=x\sin x$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: In your example $f^{-1}(0)$ is unbounded.

Comment: See [Is it possible to have the set $f^{-1}(\lbrace x \rbrace)$ perfect for every $x$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138905/is-it-possible-to-have-the-set-f-1-lbrace-x-rbrace-perfect-for-every-x) and and my [24 November 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=278635) on locally recurrent functions. The requirement that each of the $x$-level sets is bounded is straightforward to achieve once you have an example that works otherwise --- just take an example that maps from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ and extend by periodicity (as @Moishe Cohen indicates below).

Comment: Regarding my comment beginning with "The requirement that each of the $x$-level sets is bounded is straightforward", what I said doesn't work, but it's even easier than this. Just take any example that maps $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ and extend this to a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ by letting the extended function be constant on the complement of $[0,1].$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Such an extension (by a constant $c$) will violate the "bounded preimage" conditionsince $f^{-1}(c)$ will be unbounded. Also, the image of such a function will be bounded, so there will be points with empty preimage. Maybe you mean something else, such as an extension by $f(x+n)=f(x)+n$.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen: Yes, I agree. Given that I'm in the middle of something else and somewhat distracted, I should have left my original comment a bit more vague and said "and extend in the way that Moishe Cohen suggested". For what it's worth, I simply googled my name and "locally recurrent" to get the mathoverflow question and the old sci.math post, which required no real thought on my part, and apparently no real thought on my part was used in what else I said!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $h: [0,1]\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$ be a surjective continuous function such that $h(0)=(0,0)$, $h(1)=(1,1)$. Extend this function to a map 
$$
H: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}^2
$$
so that 
$$
H(t+ n)= H(t) + (n,n)
$$
for every $n\in {\mathbb Z}, t\in {\mathbb R}$. Lastly, take $f$ to the the composition of $H$ with the coordinate projection to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Note also that, since $h$ is surjective, for every $x\in {\mathbb R}$, $f^{-1}(x)$ has the cardinality of continuum. I do not know examples where **all**  these preimages are countably infinite.

Comment: @pisco125: Consider a nowhere differentiable continuous function $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=0, f^{-1}(1)=1$. (Non-differentiability at the end-points is understood as nonexistence of one-sided derivatives.) Then extend $f$ to the rest of the real line by $f(t+n)=f(t)+n$.  Then $f: R\to R$ is nowhere differentiable and has the property that $f^{-1}(n)=\{n\}$ for every integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

First define $f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ as follow: Take  a continuous surjection $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$ with $g(0)=(0,0)$ and $g(1)=(1,1).$ Let $p_1(x,y)=x$ for $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,1].$ Let  $f(x)=p_1(g(x))$ for $x\in [0,1].$

For $x\in [0,1]$  each member of $g^{-1}(\{x\}\times [0,1])$ belongs to $f^{-1}\{x\}.$  Now $g$ is a surjection; therefore the cardinal of $f^{-1}\{x\}$ is the cardinal of $\Bbb R.$

For $x\in \Bbb R$ let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x$ (an older notation for Floor$(x)$.)

Now for any $x\in \Bbb R$ define $f(x)=[x]+f(x-[x]).$

Reference topics for the function $g$: Space-filling curve, Peano curve.

Comment: I hadn't read the A by Moishe Cohen before posting this.  I made an incorrect comment to the Q and decided to immediately make up for it

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions where probability theory can give you a great intuition on how to explicitly construct such a function.

Consider a two-sided Brownian motion $(B_x)_{x\in \Bbb R}$, and then let $f(x)=B_x+x$.

I claim that with probability $1$, the function $f$ has the two properties you want. It is trivially continuous. Moreover the strong law of large numbers shows that $$\lim_{|x| \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1,\;\;\;\;\;a.s.$$ which easily implies that $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is bounded and nonempty for any $a \in \Bbb R.$ Furthermore, using a time-inversion property together with the strong Markov property and the fact that Brownian motion returns to $0$ unboundedly often, one can show that $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is infinite (in fact, uncountable) for any $a \in \Bbb R$.